# Is the prometheus-to-sd required for GKE? Can I delete it?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, grafana

A while back a `GKE` cluster got created which came with a `daemonset` of:

```
kubectl get daemonsets --all-namespaces
...
kube-system   prometheus-to-sd           6         6         6       3            6           beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux                                                355d
```

Can I delete this `daemonset` without issue? 
What is it being used for?
What functionality would I be losing without it?

Answer (score 3):

### **TL;DR**

**Even if you delete it, it will be back.**

---

### A little bit more explanation

Citing explanation by user @Yasen what `prometheus-to-sd` is:

> prometheus-to-sd is a simple component that can scrape metrics stored in [prometheus text format](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/) from one or multiple components and push them to the Stackdriver. Main requirement: k8s cluster should run on GCE or GKE.
>
> [Github.com: Prometheus-to-sd](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/tree/master/prometheus-to-sd)

Assuming that the command deleting this daemonset will be:

`$ kubectl delete daemonset prometheus-to-sd --namespace=kube-system`

**Executing this command will indeed delete the daemonset but it will be back after a while.**

`prometheus-to-sd` daemonset is managed by **Addon-Manager** which will recreate deleted daemonset back to original state.

Below is the part of the `prometheus-to-sd` daemonset `YAML` definition which states that this daemonset is managed by `addonmanager`:

```
  labels:
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
```

You can read more about it by following: [Github.com: Kubernetes: addon-manager](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/addon-manager)

---

Deleting this daemonset is strictly connected to the monitoring/logging solution you are using with your `GKE` cluster. There are 2 options:

- Stackdriver logging/monitoring
- Legacy logging/monitoring

#### Stackdriver logging/monitoring

You need to completely disable logging and monitoring of your `GKE` cluster to delete this daemonset.

You can do it by following a path:

`GCP -> Kubernetes Engine -> Cluster -> Edit -> Kubernetes Engine Monitoring -> Set to disabled`.

[image: Disabling Stackdriver]

#### Legacy logging/monitoring

If you are using a legacy solution which is available to `GKE` version `1.14`, you need to disable the option of `Legacy Stackdriver Monitoring` by following the same path as above.

[image: Disabling Legacy]

Let me know if you have any questions in that.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR - it's ok

Assuming your context, I suppose, it's ok to shutdown `prometheus` component of your cluster.
Except cases when reports, alerts and monitoring - are critical parts of your system.

## Let dive in the sources of `GCP`

As per [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/tree/master/prometheus-to-sd) at GoogleCloudPlatform:

> prometheus-to-sd is a simple component that can scrape metrics stored in [prometheus text format](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/) from one or multiple components and push them to the Stackdriver. Main requirement: k8s cluster should run on GCE or GKE.

## `Prometheus`

From their [Prometheus Github Page](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus):

> The Prometheus monitoring system and time series database.

To get a picture what is it for - you can read awesome guide on Prometheus: [Prometheus Monitoring : The Definitive Guide in 2019 – devconnected](https://devconnected.com/the-definitive-guide-to-prometheus-in-2019/)

Also, there are hundreds of videos on their Youtube channel [Prometheus Monitoring](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4pLFely0-Odea4B2NL1nWA)

## Your questions

So, answering to your questions:

> Can I delete this daemonset without issue?

It depends. As I said, you can. Except cases when reports, alerts and monitoring - are critical parts of your system.

> What is it being used for

It's a [TSDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database) for monitoring

> what functionality would I be loosing without it?

- metrics
- → therefore [dashboards](https://prometheus.io/docs/visualization/grafana/)
- → therefore [alerting](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/)